# Artifactory depoyment using Jenkins failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, apache-httpclient-4.x

Artifactory version - **7.5.5**

Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version - **3.6.2**

Maven Integration Plugin version - **3.6**

Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin version - **4.5.10-2.0**

Pipeline Script :

```
node {
  withMaven(maven: 'RnDMaven') { {
    def server = Artifactory.server('RnDArtifactory')
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
    rtMaven.deployer server : server , releaseRepo : "MGB", snapshotRepo : "MGB"
    def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install' 
  }
}
```

I used the above configuration and pipeline script to do an Artifactory maven build, thus I get the following error. Did various things to solve it such as changing the version of plugins and even downloaded latest version of Jenkins but the result was the same.

**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.**

The error cause was the above mentioned. Various solutions found in the internet and the artifactory forum was pointing to the conflict in the versions of plugin. But even after the upgrade I get the same result. Complete trace is given below.

> [ERROR]
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded()
>   listener has failed:  java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   INSTANCE  at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:37)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:170)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE  at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:35)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:122)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.buildConnectionManager(PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.build(PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.java:113)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:177)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:159)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.executeGetRequest(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:216)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getVersion(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBaseClient.getArtifactoryVersion(ArtifactoryBaseClient.java:127)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.tryChecksumDeploy(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:717)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:676)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:379)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deploy$4(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:45)
>     at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deploy(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$null$1(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:33)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [ERROR] Internal error:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded()
>   listener has failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded()
>   listener has failed:      at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded()
>   listener has failed:      at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:170)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  ... 11
>   more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   INSTANCE  at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:37)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:173)
>     ... 16 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE  at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:35)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:122)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.buildConnectionManager(PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.java:143)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.build(PreemptiveHttpClientBuilder.java:113)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:177)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:159)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.executeGetRequest(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:216)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getVersion(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBaseClient.getArtifactoryVersion(ArtifactoryBaseClient.java:127)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.tryChecksumDeploy(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:717)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:676)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:379)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deploy$4(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:45)
>     at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deploy(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$null$1(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:33)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
node {
    def server = Artifactory.server('RnDArtifactory')
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
    rtMaven.tool = 'RnDMaven'
    rtMaven.deployer server : server , releaseRepo : "MGB", snapshotRepo : "MGB"
    def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install' 
}
```

This will promise that the 'RnDMaven' Maven tool is used. I'm not sure it will help, but this is the official way to run Maven Artifactory jobs.

Example is here: https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile

Documentation is here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenBuildswithArtifactory

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @yadhavi but it doesn't solve the issue.